# Cracking pdf file with arabic password using hashcat

Tags: encryption, salt

I have been doing some test on password strength using arabic passwords and try to crack it using hashcat and when i used a non salted hash like a custom generated md5 hash and tried using --hex-charset parameter and it works like a charm but when i try it on pdf files it is not working i even decreased the password to 1 character

in case you are wondering:

- i followed this blog http://blog.bitcrack.net/2013/09/cracking-hashes-with-other-language.html but works only for non salted hashes.
- i used pdf2jhon.py to extract the hashes.
  yes using the above steps it can also work for english.
- --hex-salt is not supported on 10500(pdf format)

My assumptions are:

1.maybe the pseudo random salt generator takes chars from the password itself

2.the password hashing algorithm stores the password in unknown charset format when the password is from non-English chars

So my question is:

1.is there another workaround on this(is it possible)?

2.if my 2nd guess is correct please tell me what unicode?

**UPDATE**
after researching i found the problem is the tool used to encrypt the file uses non ASCI characters when using non ASCI characters in my case arabic i am trying to use utf-8 format like D985 can someone tell me which unicode microsoft office and adobe acrobat use when using non ASCI characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tool-specific questions are off topic here and so are reference requests. You should be able to ask tools specific questions on SuperUser, and there is also a Software Recommendations site for the 3rd question.

Comment: i am updating the question wait.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get things to work with the application you can try and use the source code instead. A lot of these tools are open source. Then you can specify the character set directly and/or use an Arabic dictionary.

The password itself is not stored when a password is hashed. That means that the precise encoding details are lost - the password hashing algorithms themselves process bytes, not characters usually. Nowadays a lot of password hashes and applications default to UTF-8 though, which can encode any character set. UTF-16 and UTF-16LE can also be tried, with and without BOM header.

However, to find out which character set is used just from the hash (instead of, say, a protocol specification) you can only try.